# redirect user to a a page after he login

Tags: php, laravel

I have a home page that has a link "Create Post" to create a new post (`<a href="{!! route('post.create') !!}">Create Post</a>`).

When this link is clicked, if the user is authenticated he should be allowed to access this create post page.

But if the user is not authenticated the user should be redirected to the login/register page. After he login he should be redirected to the create post page.

I have the code below to do this but when the user dont have an account and click in "Create Post" he is redirected to the login page if the user login it appears the error:

```
 Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User, instance of App\User given.
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users ', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::post('/post/store', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@store',
        'as'   => 'post.store'
    ]);

    Route::get('/createPost', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@create',
        'as'   => 'post.create'
    ]);
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**Login Controller:**

```
 class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/createPost');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `intended` method to redirect to the page they were trying to access.

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

There are you are seeing is due to passing in a `User` model instance, when it should be a `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`. Remove the type-hinting from the method signature and it should work:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended('/createPost');
}
```

Be sure your `User` model implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` contract.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the login but not for the register. Should not be the same code for the RegisterController?

Comment: Yeah you'll do the same with registeration, redirect with intended.

Comment: Exactly the same of : protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended('/createPost');
} right? Because, with that code, when the user register he is being redirected to the homepage, not the create post page.

Comment: `'/createPost'` is just a fallback route so you'd probably want to use `return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo)` or similar. It is only used in the case when the intended route is not available. The homepage or a user's account page would be a safe fallback.

Comment: Tks, but the register still dont work with that method!